# Ruby on Rails: redirect_to not working after create and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to `redirect_to slider_path` after a user submits their email. Currently, only the success message is displayed without a redirect. Here's the code:

```
class Splash::SubscribersController < ApplicationController

def create

  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])

  if @subscriber.save
    success = true
    message = "Success! We'll let you know when we launch."
  else
    success = false
    message = "Fail."
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { 
      if success
        flash[:success] = message
        redirect_to slider_path
      else 
        flash[:error] = message
      end
      redirect_to root_path 
    }
    format.json { render :json => { :success => success, :message => message }.to_json }
  end  
 end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace this part of your code:

```
  if success
    flash[:success] = message
    redirect_to slider_path
  else 
    flash[:error] = message
  end
  redirect_to root_path
```

with this:

```
  if success
    flash[:success] = message
    redirect_to slider_path
  else 
    flash[:error] = message
    redirect_to root_path 
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

[Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) states:

An action may contain only a single render or a single redirect. Attempting to try to do either again will result in a DoubleRenderError:

```
def do_something
  redirect_to :action => "elsewhere"
  render :action => "overthere" # raises DoubleRenderError
end
```

If you need to redirect on the condition of something, then be sure to add “and return” to halt execution.

```
def do_something
  redirect_to(:action => "elsewhere") and return if monkeys.nil?
  render :action => "overthere" # won't be called if monkeys is nil
end
```

Note the use of `and return`

Answer (score 4):

Neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Answer (score 2):

Add a return statement after your redirect. If the action also renders a template by default, any redirects need to be followed by a return statement.

```
if success
  flash[:success] = message
  redirect_to slider_path
  return                    # <= Add a return.
else
  flash[:error] = message
end
redirect_to root_path
```